# Android Emulator opening view at 320*480 when set to 480*854

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to set up an AVD for a 480*854 device. The AVD seems fine but when it opens my app the SurfaceView that I create is opening at 320*480 rather than 480*854. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

cheers

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Make sure minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are specified in the  attribute of AndroidManifest.xml. This stops Android from running in 'compatibility mode'.

Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

First open your project and right click on your project
see Run As -> Run Configurations.

There are three tag

1. Android
2. Target
3. Common

now click on 2. Target and select your device and apply and run.

Comment: Hi Prashant, thanks very much for your reply. I think you're presuming I'm using Eclipse or something though which I'm not ;) Can you give me an idea what I should do using the standard toolset? cheers

Comment: Means r u not using eclipse? than what r u using for development?

Comment: I'm using an app called TextMate on the Mac. It's basically a very flexible text editor that has scripts to connect to the command-line tools so if there's a way to do it from the command-line I can probably figure it out but I don't really know what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

What are you specifying for `minSdkVersion` or `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest's `uses-sdk` tag? If you don't tell android what version of the platform you're developing for it will run your app in compatibility mode assuming it does not know how to handle different screen sizes and densities.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the replay. I didn't have anything set for those. Am trying with minSdkVersion set to 3 and targetSdkVersion set to 6. minSdkVersion is working OK but trying to specify targetSdkVersion gives me a build error - 'error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'targetSdkVersion' in package 'android''?

Comment: OK - sorted that, I needed to build against a newer version of Android for it to 'get' targetSdkVersion. This has solved it - thanks very much!

Comment: You're quite welcome! Please accept the answer if it worked for you. :)